# how to center a single element in slick.js jquery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel, slick.js

I am using [slick plugin](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) and I have problem with centering items when there is only one element. My code:

```
$('#divId').slick({
   dots: false,
   infinite: true,
   speed: 300,
   slidesToShow: 1,
   centerMode: true,
   variableWidth: true
});
```

If I have few elements in the container everything is OK (centerMode works great) but when I have only one element in slick queue - it goes to the right hand side.

[Real example](http://test.ominposrednika.pl/Announcements/Index/111)

I couldn't reproduce that problem on jsfiddle. I coppied my code there but everything seems to be ok there: [jfFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a0jLbkdq/1/)

Does anybody know where is the problem ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please reproduce the problem in fx. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net).

Comment: try `.slick-track { margin: 0 auto; }`

Comment: Where did you put your slick initializing code? The same you wrote above. In which file?

Comment: inside block:  $(function () {    });